# How to avoid multiple subscribers of a observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have one ModalControllerService that has one observable to return a value from Modal.
This work good when i have only one component that open a modal in one page, but when i have more than one component in same page, all subscribers subscribe in the same time.

What i do to avoid this, has one method to differenciate each subscribe of a subscriber ?

```js
@Injectable()
export class ModalControllerService {
  private modalStack: ModalStackObject[] = [];
  private afterDismissObservable = new Subject<any>();
  onAfterDismiss$ = this.afterDismissObservable.asObservable();

  public get lastModal() {
    return this.modalStack[this.modalStack.length - 1];
  }

  close(model?: any) {
    if (this.modalStack && this.modalStack.length > 0) {
      this.lastModal.component.dismiss()
        .then(() => {
          this.afterDismissObservable.next(model);
          this.modalStack.pop();
        });
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  ...
});
export class SomeComponent {
  private modalSubscription: Subscription;
  value: any;

  constructor(modalCtrl: ModalControllerService){
    this.modalSubscription = this.modalCtrl.onAfterDismiss$.subscribe(result => {
      this.value = result;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.modalSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: are components initiating at a same time?

Comment: It's one page that has some components that open modal and all this is initiating at same time, i think.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it happens because your components are initializing at a same time. When component initializes, bydefault constructor function runs. So that could be a problem for you. I can't say too much on it but what you can do is you can wrap onAfterDismiss$.subscribe() within any custom function

eg. click function of a button.

**Component-1**

```
constructor(modalCtrl: ModalControllerService){
        this.modalSubscription = this.modalCtrl.onAfterDismiss$.subscribe(result => {
             this.value = result;
        });
}
```

**Component-2**

```
constructor(modalCtrl: ModalControllerService){}

click(){                         // it will subscribe to the observable when button is clicked.
        this.modalSubscription = this.modalCtrl.onAfterDismiss$.subscribe(result => {
             this.value = result;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not worked to me. My workaround now is pass one key with subscribe value to differentiate each subscriber.